# Dependency wierdness - Can't install printer driver

Tags: ubuntu, printer

I'm trying to install the driver for my Canon-MX390 printer but when I run the file from Canon it complains about dependencies I already have;

Ubuntu 20.0.4LTS

```
$ sudo ./install.sh 

Canon Inkjet Printer Driver
Version 3.90
Copyright CANON INC. 2001-2013
All Rights Reserved.

==================================================
Command executed = rpm -Uvh ./packages/cnijfilter-common-3.90-1.x86_64.rpm
rpm: RPM should not be used directly install RPM packages, use Alien instead!
rpm: However assuming you know what you are doing...
error: Failed dependencies:
    /bin/sh is needed by cnijfilter-common-3.90-1.x86_64
    cups is needed by cnijfilter-common-3.90-1.x86_64
    libc.so.6()(64bit) is needed by cnijfilter-common-3.90-1.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by cnijfilter-common-3.90-1.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit) is needed by cnijfilter-common-3.90-1.x86_64
    libcups.so.2()(64bit) is needed by cnijfilter-common-3.90-1.x86_64
    libdl.so.2()(64bit) is needed by cnijfilter-common-3.90-1.x86_64
    libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by cnijfilter-common-3.90-1.x86_64
    libpopt.so.0()(64bit) is needed by cnijfilter-common-3.90-1.x86_64
    libpthread.so.0()(64bit) is needed by cnijfilter-common-3.90-1.x86_64
    popt is needed by cnijfilter-common-3.90-1.x86_64
```

I have cups, libc and libpthread already; so this doesn't make sense, any suggestions?

Comment: Add the OS that you are using and the name of the archive that contains the `install.sh` script to the question.

Comment: You’re trying to install RPMs on a Debian-based system, which won’t work. I don’t know how to make your MX390 printer work on your system, so I’ll leave this as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @StephenKitt Argh! Doh. Thanks! I'll see what else they have